# How to check Mime Type (Content Type) of a file?

Tags: apex, lightning, upload

I want to restrict a file upload based on extension type and mime type. However i found the fileextension field will always be null in before or after insert contentversion trigger and filtype field on content will have some different form of string. Ex- For excl filetype is "EXCEL_X" and file extension is null in after insert trigger. I want to get the mime type like 'applicaton/xlxs' or somewhat like that.

Comment: @DavidReed I checked that answer earlier, The mime type can be multiple for excel file only. Let me know how can we identify the mime type by just seeing  Filetype

Comment: `FileType` isn't a MIME type. It's a Salesforce-specific string. If that's what you're after, it'd be helpful if you could clarify that in your question, because the actual MIME type (like `'text/csv'`) isn't available.

Comment: @DavidReed Is there any way to get Salesforce specific string for different type of file ? Any documention if you know.. Also, Thanks i edited my question.

Comment: not that I know of, besides uploading files of various types and looking at the field after Salesforce populates it.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about checking the file type in before insert, Better to go with PathOnClient field on ContentVersion.It is not null in both before and in after trigger.

```
trigger ContentVersiontrigger on ContentVersion (before insert) {
    for(ContentVersion cv:Trigger.new){
        if(cv.PathOnClient==cv.Title+'.jpg'){
          cv.adderror('error');
        }
    }}
```

PathOnClient will contain the Title and file type separated by "." e.g PathOnClient=download.png

If you are going for 'after trigger' on ContentVersion, then Yes you will get FileType 'EXCEL_X' whose extension is XLSX.

Again, Here pathOnclient will contain the file extension which will take out you from all the problem.

Comment: Hi Sanket, Is it possible to get mime type from any file ? like 'application/xlsx' ..Like the way we have content-type field on attachment

Comment: ContentVersion does not contain mime type field as I could check in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the field `PathOnClient`

> Description - The complete path of the document. One of the fields that
>   determines the FileType.

code snippet inside your trigger/handler should be -

```
     ContentVersion attachedFile = new ContentVersion();

   if (attachedFile.PathOnClient.endsWithIgnoreCase('xlsx') || attachedFile.PathOnClient.endsWithIgnoreCase('xls')){
    attachedFile.addError('xls and xlsx files are allowed');
    }
```

Comment: Hi Bennie, Is it possible to get mime type from any file ? like 'application/xlsx' ..Like the way we have content-type field on attachment

Comment: The field `ContentType` will contain the MIMEType of a file in the Attachment object. Not sure about ContentVersion